# Highcharts Pie with Drilldown: How to change the color of each subcategory

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to create a pie chart with drill down, but color each subgroup in the drill down pie chart a different color. Right now, I get the default colors assigned to the data sets. The parent pie chart will have total count of active alerts for each environment i.e. DEV,DR, PROD, NPRD and when you drill down to each environment, display another pie chart that has 3 groupings 'Critical','Warning','Info.' Critical colored red, warning colored orange, info colored yellow.

Here is my code which works perfectly except the coloring of the subgroups of the drilldown pie chart.

```
Highcharts.chart('container_alerts_environment', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Alerts Grouped By Environment',
        align: 'center'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the slices to view alerts. Source: <a href="http://vi-operations.bbtnet.com/Data/Active Nutanix Alarms.html" target="_blank">Alerts Data</a>',
        align: 'center'
    },

    accessibility: {
        announceNewData: {
            enabled: true
        },
        point: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderRadius: 5,
            dataLabels: [{
                enabled: true,
                distance: 15,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }, {
                enabled: true,
                distance: '-30%',
                filter: {
                    property: 'percentage',
                    operator: '>',
                    value: 0
                },
                format: '{point.y}',
                style: {
                    fontSize: '0.9em',
                    textOutline: 'none'
                }
            }]
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
        },

    series: [
        {
            name: 'Alert Count',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [
                {
                    name: 'DEV',
                    y: 19,
                    drilldown: 'DEV'
                },
                {
                    name: 'NPRD',
                    y: 8,
                    drilldown: 'NPRD'
                },
                {
                    name: 'DR',
                    y: 11,
                    drilldown: 'DR'
                },
                {
                    name: 'PROD',
                    y: 23,
                    drilldown: 'PROD'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    drilldown: {
        series: [
            {
                name: 'DEV',
                id: 'DEV',
                data: [
                    [
                        'Critical',
                        10
                    ],
                    [
                        'Warning',
                        7
                    ],
                    [
                        'Info',
                        2
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'NPRD',
                id: 'NPRD',
                data: [
                    [
                        'Critical',
                        3
                    ],
                    [
                        'Warning',
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        'Info',
                        1
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'DR',
                id: 'DR',
                data: [
                    [
                        'Critical',
                        1
                    ],
                    [
                        'Warning',
                        4
                    ],
                    [
                        'Info',
                        6
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'PROD',
                id: 'PROD',
                data: [
                    [
                        'Critical',
                        12
                    ],
                    [
                        'Warning',
                        8
                    ],
                    [
                        'Info',
                        3
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Adding the color attribute inside each dataset does not work, I get an error of unexpected token. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own! Inside my drilldown series, I was using double brackets instead of bracket and then encase my data in curly braces.